# Magento 1 category page show subcategories before products

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-products, category-view

**I have a magento 1 website and I want to display subcategories before products on the category page.**

> In the **admin page -> on Catalog, Manage Categories -> Display Settings
>   -> Display Mode is set to Static Block and Products.**
>
> **The Is Anchor option is enabled.**

The catalog/category/view.phtml contains:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I checked and on my page it goes to "isMixedMode" so until now everything is ok.

The problem is that in my case the products appear before the subcategories, even if the " $this->getCmsBlockHtml()" is called before "$this->getProductListHtml()".

I tried to edit the catalog.xml but with no results. This is how my catalog.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

Supported layout update handles (action):
- catalog_product_gallery
- catalog_product_compare_index

Supported layout update handles (special):
- default
- catalog_category_default
- catalog_category_layered
- catalog_product_view

-->
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

    <default>
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</reference>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="left"> 
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="category.menu"  template="page/html/category.phtml"  before="-">

            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
    </default>


<!--
Category default layout
-->

    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <action method="addAttribute"><attribute>listing_text</attribute></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

<!--
Category layered navigation layout
-->


    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
           <!-- <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>-->
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <action method="addAttribute"><attribute>listing_text</attribute></action>
                    <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
<!--
Compare products page
-->

    <catalog_product_compare_index translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Compare List</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_compare_index>

    <customer_account_index>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_index>

<!--
Product view
-->

    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="fileuploader/fileuploader" name="product.attachments" as="product.attachments"  template="fileuploader/desc_attachments.phtml"/>
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/></block>
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block>

                <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>3</limit></action>
                </block>

 <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="product.info.related" as="related_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>related</type><limit>3</limit></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                    <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
                </block>






                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

    </catalog_product_view>

<!--
Additional block dependant on product type
-->
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Virtual)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_virtual" name="product.info.virtual" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.virtual.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>



<!--
Product send to friend
-->

    <catalog_product_send translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Email to a Friend</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_send" name="product.send" template="catalog/product/send.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_send>

<!--
Product additional images gallery popup
-->

    <catalog_product_gallery translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product Image Gallery Popup</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_gallery" name="catalog_product_gallery" template="catalog/product/gallery.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_gallery>

<!--
SEO Site Map
-->

    <catalog_seo_sitemap translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Common)</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/template_container" name="seo.sitemap.container" template="catalog/seo/sitemap/container.phtml">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="seo.sitemap.links" as="links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.top" as="pager_top" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.bottom" as="pager_bottom" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_category translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Category List)</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="catalog_seo_sitemap" />
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Categories</title></action>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_category" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/sitemap.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.bottom</pager></action>
                <action method="setItemsTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>categories</title></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>Products Sitemap</label><url helper="catalog/map/getProductUrl"/><title>Products Sitemap</title></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_category>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_category_tree translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Category Tree)</label>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.pager.top" />
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.pager.bottom" />
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_pager" name="seo.sitemap.tree.pager.top" as="pager_top" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_pager" name="seo.sitemap.tree.pager.bottom" as="pager_bottom" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
            <remove name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" />
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_tree_category" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap_tree" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/tree.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.tree.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.tree.pager.bottom</pager></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_category_tree>

    <catalog_seo_sitemap_product translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Product List)</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="catalog_seo_sitemap" />
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.container">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>Products</title></action>
            <block type="catalog/seo_sitemap_product" name="seo.sitemap.sitemap" as="sitemap" after="pager_top" template="catalog/seo/sitemap.phtml">
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.top</pager></action>
                <action method="bindPager"><pager>seo.sitemap.pager.bottom</pager></action>
                <action method="setItemsTitle" translate="title" module="catalog"><title>products</title></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="seo.sitemap.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>Categories Sitemap</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl"/><title>Categories Sitemap</title></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_seo_sitemap_product>
</layout>
```

In the admin page, on Catalog, Manage Categories, Custom Design I have:

Custom Layout Update - empty

Page Layout - 2 columns with left bar

So the subcategories should appear before the products. Am I missing something? Please help me because I can't figure this out. Thank you!